# Google Cloud Engine: How to route traffic on port 80 when using HTTPS load balancer

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I'm using HTTPS load balancer for my website and it's working well if I visit: https://www.vietnamspotlight.com.

However, if I visit the URL with `http`, i.e http://vietnamspotlight.com, then I always get error from Google that says the request was not found.

Then I tried to update load balancer by adding a new IP, port and protocol to use with HTTP in **Frontend configuration** session. See the image below for reference (the IPs for HTTP and HTTPS have been removed from the image):

[image: Load balancer settings]

After that, I switch to DNS configuration of the domain provider and tried to add another A records that point to new IP to deal with requests with HTTP protocol. It means I'm using two A records at same host `@`, each points to a different value, one for the HTTP and one for the HTTPS. See the image below for reference (the values have been changed to fake IP addresses):

[image: DNS settings]

Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are configuring your load balancer incorrectly. You must use the same TCP/IP address for both HTTP and HTTPS.

By configuring two different IP addresses for your website in DNS, you are in effect providing two IP addresses to clients to select from. Depending on the client and the DNS server, your clients will go to one IP address or the other in a round-robin style. This of course is not what you want.

DNS servers do not know the difference between HTTP and HTTPS when making DNS resolution decisions. DNS servers translate domain names to IP addresses. The protocol (HTTP / HTTPS) is not part of the translation decision.

This means that you need to configure your Google Load Balancer (HTTP(S) Load Balancing - Layer 7) with two frontends. The first frontend is HTTP, the second frontend is HTTPS. Both use the same IP address.

**IMPORTANT:**

An important step is to create the static IP address as global before creating the load balancer. If you create the IP address during the step to create the first frontend, you won't be able to select the same IP address when you create the second frontend.

Delete the incorrect entry in your DNS server. You may have to wait a while for the TTL (Time-To-Live) to timeout for your DNS entries. While waiting go to the next step.

Go back to the Google Cloud Console. Select your load balancer. Delete your HTTP frontend. Save the load balancer. Now go back and configure a new frontend for HTTP selecting the same IP address that you used for the HTTPS frontend.

Comment: thanks for pointing out some good points. I followed your advice by adding static IP address and attached it to load balancer in Frontend Configuration for both HTTP and HTTPS protocols. When I access the IP address on port 80 it works but 443 (for https) it does not work, browser giving me error: "This site can’t be reached".

Comment: It can take a few minutes (5 - 20) for the load balancer to reconfigure. You will also have to wait for the DNS entries to timeout (TTL). The DNS entries are cached by DNS servers. Make sure that you did update the DNS server with the correct IP address.

Comment: I've been waiting the whole morning. Plus the error occurs in the load balancer not with DNS settings because I can access the IP using HTTP protocol, but HTTPs not working. Both HTTP and HTTPs have been added to load balancer under "Frontend configuration" though.

Comment: Step 1: Make sure that the DNS server has the right IP address for the load balancer. Step 2: Make sure that the two frontends are using the same IP address. Step 3: Flush your computers DNS (Windows: `ipconfig /flushdns`). Step 4: Use a DNS Testing Tool (Google search DNS Test). Step 5: What was the TTL set on your DNS server. It could be set for days which means you will have to wait for the same time. NOTE: the domain `www.vietnamspotlight.com` is not setup correctly. Is this the correct domain name? (Namecheap, Inc.). `vietnamspotlight.com` is setup correctly, DNS entry for `www` ?

Comment: Your problem is most likely that your DNS server is not setup for www. Create a CNAME for `www` pointing to `vietnamspotlight.com`

Comment: I didn't test on domain level, I tested the IP address. For HTTPs connection browser always show the error "This site can’t be reached". I tried telnet on port 443 and even the connection was established it ends after just 3 to 5 seconds.
IMPORTANT: For the backend service configuration, I use instance group that maps incoming traffic to port 80 only. I also tried with comma separated values, i.e: 80,443 but it doesn't work too

Comment: it works like a charm now, maybe testing IP on browser won't tell the whole thing. Thank bro!!!

Comment: Your site look very nice. Next item. You will want to redirect all visitors that go to HTTP to redirect to HTTPS. There are lots of examples on StackOverflow on how to redirect webservers to HTTPS.